# Android multi-activities app best way to detect application going in background

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I am developing an Android application with number of activities. My MainActivity (Starting activity) has code to fetch updated data from server. I want to fetch updated data from server every time user launch application (1st launch or move application in foreground).
1st launch is fine i fetch data. But when user is on some other activity and minimize my app and open again it starts from last state. At this point how can i detect application is starting again so that i can fetch data again.

I have already checked onResume(), onPause() methods but they belong to individual activities. I want to catch event on application level, as we normally do in iOS applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't. You'll have to find a way to filter the onResume()/onPause() from all the activities to find out the application went to background.

A suggestion:

```
 public abstract class AbstractActivity extends Activity{
    private static long pauseTime=0;
    private static final long MIN_PAUSE_TIME = 3000;

    protected void onPause(){
      super.onPause();
      pauseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    protected void onResume(){
      super.onResume();
      if(System.currentTimeMillis()-pauseTime > MIN_PAUSE_TIME){
         // do server stuff
      }
    }
 }
```

and then make all your activities extend this one.

Comment: thanks for the edit. I typed this whole thing by heart and it was bound to have some typos on methods name. I'm usually just use auto-complete all the time.

Comment: you should use System.nanoTime() to do time measurements, because System.currentTimeMillis() can change values due to correction of time.

Answer (score 0):

I would have said the best place to start is to read the documentation on the Activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

My first thought is rather than to run the code in `onCreate()` (which is what I assume you're doing), to place the code in `onStart()`, (but `onResume()` may also be appropriate) - have a read of the docs and it should become apparent which one is best to use for your application

Answer (score -1):

Create one class which extends to an application and then implement onPause() and onResume().
i.e as follows..

```
 /**
* Top-level Application class for the your app.
 */
public class DummyApp extends Application {
    /* package */ static final String LOG_TAG = "DummyApp";
  onPause(){
  super.onPause();
  //do whatever you want--
  }

  onResume(){
  super.onResume();
   //Do whatever you want --
  }
  }
```

Then mention this app name "DummyApp" in AndroidManifest.xml as follows

```
<application android:name="DummyApp"
             android:label="@string/apLabel"
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
```

I think this may solve ...